# To find the linear transformation from the given data

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> let $B = {(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ and $B' = {(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (-1, -1, 1)}$ be ordered bases of $V = {R}^3$. Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation such that
> $$[T]_{B', B'} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
> Find $[T_{B, B'}]$ and hence write $T(x, y, z)$

Here is my attempt

Let $u$ be a vector in space B' and let $(a, b, c)$ be the coordinates of the that vector wrt the given basis.

Solving it gives us the relation
$$ c = z$$
$$ b = y + z$$
$$ a = x + z $$

Now the coordinates of the transformation of the vector can be obtained by multipying the coordinate vector to the right of the given transformation matrix. So the transformed coordinates are $(a, c, b)$

Now to get the vector back we simply combine the new coordinates with the basis

$$ a (1, 0, 0) + c (0, 1, 0) + b (-1, -1, 1)$$
$$ = (a- b, c -b, b)$$
$$ = (x - y, - y, y + z)$$

hence this would be the value of $T(x,y,z)$

But it does not match with the answer which says it should be $(x - y, -y + z, y)$

It is given that

$$[T]_{B, B'} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where am i going wrong?